# Forms Authentication not working in Azure app service

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-app-service

I have a .NET MVC 4 application with .net framework 4.6.1 with forms authentication enabled. Is it possible to have this hosted in Azure app services. I am not finding an option in app services to have forms authentication enabled and getting the attached message when I navigate to the website. 
I have the application taking me to the login page on a local server with IIS however not being able to make it work in App services. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by fixing a connection string which was  causing an error however the message for default document not set in azure may have been misleading.